# Primefaces File Download not working?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Trying to get a simple file download working and all I am getting is a hanging AJAX status bar and that's it. My backing bean outputs render the correct name on the prep and the download.

Am I doing this wrong? both outputs seem to me to be correct.

JSF 2.0
Primefaces 3.4

```
        <h:form>
            <p:commandButton id="downloadLink" value="Download" actionListener="#{filemanagement.prepDownload}"> 
                <p:fileDownload value="#{filemanagement.download}" />
            </p:commandButton>
        </h:form>
```

Backing bean:

```
private DefaultStreamedContent download;

public void setDownload(DefaultStreamedContent download) {
    this.download = download;
}

public DefaultStreamedContent getDownload() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("GET = " + download.getName());
    return download;
}

public void prepDownload() throws Exception {
    File file = new File("C:\\file.csv");
    InputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
    ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    setDownload(new DefaultStreamedContent(input, externalContext.getMimeType(file.getName()), file.getName()));
    System.out.println("PREP = " + download.getName());
}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**Guide for Primefaces version >= 12.0.0**

Before PrimeFaces 11, you had to disable AJAX with DataExport. As of version 11 that's no longer needed.

[Primefaces Documentation 12.0.0](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/12_0_0/#/components/dataexporter?id=ajax-downloading)

**Guide for Primefaces version >= 10 && < 12.0.0**

For Primefaces versions before 10 you had to disable ajax on the `commandButton` with `ajax=false`.

Since version 10 that's no longer needed, see [Primefaces Documentation 10](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/10_0_0/#/components/filedownload?id=ajax-downloading).

**Guide for Primefaces version < 10:**

See [Primefaces Documentation 6.2](https://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_6_2.pdf)

> If you’d like to use PrimeFaces commandButton and commandLink, disable ajax option as
> fileDownload requires a full page refresh to present the file.

```
<h:form>
  <p:commandButton id="downloadLink" value="Download" ajax="false" actionListener="#{filemanagement.prepDownload}">
    <p:fileDownload value="#{filemanagement.download}" />
  </p:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

Comment: Thanks - Didn't prompt for a download (FF 17). But appreciate this info (missed it).

Comment: Session - On the view itself, I have 3 forms. None of them are interweaved. I have read that Primefaces and multiple forms can be sketchy.

Comment: Not sure what cascaded means in this particular instance, but I have a dialog that pops up (AJAX call) that has 3 forms (edit, import, download). So this form is part of that dialog.

Comment: I've never experienced any problems with multiple forms, as long as they are not cascaded within each other. Try to use something like Firebug to inspect what's going on. What is sent to the server, and what is being receied (if any)? Maybe any validation errors? Maybe an uncaught exception somewhere?

Comment: As long as the forms are inside the dialog, and not the other way around it's ok. Interweaved means the same as cascaded for me, sorry about that. Either you try to debug your way through it, or you provide more information we can work with.

Comment: @user2124871, not just primefaces, nested forms are illegal in regular HTML. Turn on your browser's javascript console and observe the network tab to make sure the file is being returned from the server

Comment: In my case the screen turns dark and don't dowload anything, with ajax=false works!

Answer (score 17):

Inside command button, set ajax=false and do not use action or action listener for commandlink.

```
<h:form>
  <p:commandButton id="downloadLink" value="Download" ajax="false">
    <p:fileDownload value="#{filemanagement.downloadValue}" />
  </p:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

Bean:

```
public StreamedContent getDownloadValue() throws Exception {
    StreamedContent download=new DefaultStreamedContent();
    File file = new File("C:\\file.csv");
    InputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
    ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    download = new DefaultStreamedContent(input, externalContext.getMimeType(file.getName()), file.getName()));
    System.out.println("PREP = " + download.getName());
    return download;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From PrimeFaces 10 and up you **can** use Ajax downloads!

https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/10_0_0/#/components/filedownload?id=ajax-downloading

The download will be triggered by JavaScript when you use Ajax on your command button or link.

See also:

https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/5978

Answer (score 0):

The most important thing that ia have done is turn ajax="false".

Here i have with commandlink, as you can see bellow.

In html:

```
<p:commandLink id="someId"
                value="Download"
                style="padding-left: 2em; vertical-align: middle;"
                ajax="false"
                onstart="PF('pageBlocker').show()"
                oncomplete="PF('pageBlocker').hide()">
  <p:fileDownload value="#{bean.downloadFileTemplate()}" />
</p:commandLink>
```

In Java:

```
public StreamedContent downloadFileTemplate() {
    try {
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("path_to_resource/myfile.xlsx").getFile()));

        StreamedContent fileTemplate = new DefaultStreamedContent(
                inputStream
                , "application/vnd.ms-excel"
                , "my_file.xlsx");

        return fileTemplate;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        getLog().error("Error on download...", e);
        return null;
    }
}
```