# call function , update some forms than download file

Tags: java, file, primefaces, download, commandbutton

I'm using primefaces , ı have a commandButton to  download file than reflesh page 
but it's not work same time.when ı was click   page refleshed but not downloaded file,
when second time click same button download file.
I need one click to end in two business.[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15744778/update-component-after-file-download) does not work for me.This is my code generateVaultingFiles() is my function to do some other works. createVSclicked() update some scripts , vaultSheetFile is a file to ı want to download it same time.

```
<div class="row">
<p:commandButton value="Create Vault Sheet" id="cmd_createVaultSheet"
    widgetVar="createVSBut"
    disabled="#{vaultAutoManagedBean.orderCodeUncompleted
    or vaultAutoManagedBean.selectedTask.state eq 6}"
    style="width: 90%; height: 45px; "
    action="#{vaultAutoManagedBean.generateVaultingFiles}"
    onclick="createVSclicked();" update="@form"       >
    <p:fileDownload value="#{vaultAutoManagedBean.vaultSheetFile}"/>
</p:commandButton>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16093527/primefaces-file-download-not-working

Comment: You can't download a file with ajax.

Comment: @Kukeltje its not work me can you have another solution.

Comment: 'Not work' is not something we can act upon. Debug better