# Downloading File from Linux is empty

Tags: java, linux, primefaces, websphere-7

I'm trying to download a file I just create from a path in server (Linux) file is a CSV, it has two lines, when i try to download it, it is downloaded but it's empty, If the files is large it does come complete,

Do you have any idea. I'm using primefaces p:download component.

```
File f = new File(dir.trim());
FileWriter filWrite = new FileWriter(f, Boolean.TRUE);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(filWrite);

        while(query.next()){
            // cada 50,000 crea un nuevo txt
            if(i==50000){
                dir = rutaDestino+""+prefijoArchivo+"_"+count+".csv";
                f = new File(dir.trim());// crea archivo
                filWrite = new FileWriter(f, Boolean.TRUE);
                bw.close();
                bw = new BufferedWriter(filWrite);
                i=1;
                count++;                    
            }               
            for(j=1;j<=numeroColumnas;j++){
                bw.append(query.getString(j));
                if (j<numeroColumnas){  
                  bw.append("||");
                }
            }               
            //bw.newLine();
            bw.append("\n");
        i++;
        }
        bw.close();
```

then i download the file like this:

```
private DefaultStreamedContent download;

public void prepDownload(String path) throws Exception {
    try {
        File file = new File(path);
        InputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
        ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        setDownload(new DefaultStreamedContent(input, externalContext.getMimeType(file.getName()), file.getName()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JsfUtil.showFacesMsg(
                e,
                "Error en Clase GestionResultadosMB metodo prepDownload",
                "sysErrMsg", FacesMessage.SEVERITY_FATAL);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you debug your code to see if this is actually creating a non empty file? what is query.next() returns false, it will create an empty file

Comment: I have access to the file. When i Open the file in the server, it has the two lines. If i tested in my local computer (WIndows) It does work ....

Comment: Try to check your Primefaces and check with this question  http://stackoverflow.com/a/24906013/3479860

Comment: It is already like that.... I found that websphere has a minimun size of 4096 , Im trying to get rid of that

Comment: So it works on windows? And if it seems websphere related, use that tag

Comment: Done @Kukeltje already edited